# QTablewidget is later expanded (or drawn)

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I am using `QTableWidget`, and when I open a dialog with `QTableWidget`, I notice that `QTableWidgetis` drawn later. 
The screen configuration is different, but other dialogs with the same set `QTableWidget` do not have this problem.

I know what code caused it.
It looks like a late extension because of `verticlaHeader () -> setSectionResizeMode (QHeader :: Stretch)`. The problem is, however, that setting QTableWidget equally in other dialogs does not seem like that. I've used `setSectionResizeMode` without any problems, but suddenly I have this problem.

[image: Result table image]

The picture above is not an exact picture. Because I can not take a screenshot to fit the timing.

To be more precise, the QTableWidget seems to be expanded in the picture, but the size of the QTableWidget does not change. The size of the cell changes. The size of the cell is small and increases by the height of qtableWidget according to the setting of SectionResizeMode.

```
void MyWidget::init() {

    QStringList horizontalHeader = QStringList() << "Max" << "Min";
    QStringList verticalHeader = QStringList() << "Velocity[m/s]" << "Acceleration[m/s²]" << "Density[kg/m³" << "Pressure[kg/(ms²)]";
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horizontalHeader);
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->setVerticalHeaderLabels(verticalHeader);
    for (int i = 0; i < ui.PropertyTableWidget->columnCount(); ++i)
        ui.PropertyTableWidget->verticalHeaderItem(i)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignmentFlag(Qt::AlignLeft + Qt::AlignVCenter));

    ui.PropertyTableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setFixedHeight(24);
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->SetDelegateType(TABLE_DELEGATE_TYPE_ROW);
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->setItemDelegateForRow(0, new LineEditDelegate(ui.PropertyTableWidget, -FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX, EDIT_DECIMAL, UNIT_TYPE_VELOCITY));
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->setItemDelegateForRow(1, new LineEditDelegate(ui.PropertyTableWidget, -FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX, EDIT_DECIMAL, UNIT_TYPE_ACCELERATION));
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->setItemDelegateForRow(2, new LineEditDelegate(ui.PropertyTableWidget, -FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX, EDIT_DECIMAL, UNIT_TYPE_DENSITY));
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->setItemDelegateForRow(3, new LineEditDelegate(ui.PropertyTableWidget, -FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX, EDIT_DECIMAL, UNIT_TYPE_PRESS));
    ui.PropertyTableWidget->EnableRowRemove(false);
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try once i hope it will work:

Table header costume:

```
horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed );
horizontalHeader()->setDefaultAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I solved this problem. This problem was caused by setting setSectionResizeMode () to QHeaderView :: Stretch after setting the minimum and maximum size of QTableWidget to the same value. So when I set the minimum size to 0, the problem is solved. I do not know what effect it changed the minimum size, but it was resolved anyway.